# SharePoint Workflow Best Practices

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Any Points on the SharePoint Workflow Best Practices for both SPD and VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first is sharepoint 2010 best practices:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8666.sharepoint-2010-best-practices.aspx

secondly this:

Workflow Development Tools Comparison

SPD VS VSWD

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461944.aspx

Workflow Development for SharePoint Foundation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414613.aspx

Workflow Development in SharePoint Designer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414204.aspx

Workflow Development in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461324.aspx

Best Practices and Limitations of creating Workflows using Visio and SharePoint Designer

http://sharepoint-videos.com/sp10-best-practices-workflows-visio-sharepoint-designer/

how to make them explained:

Introduction to designing and customizing workflows

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx

that should get you going and become a pro in WF development ;)